# max Java memory + TOMCAT + server with 144GB RAM

Tags: java

I did my homework and i could not find an answer for my problem.

I have a server with 144GB ram (147456MB)
I do have java JDK 1.6.0_24-b07
I also have tomcat 7.0.10.0

I would like to assign as much memory as possible.

I would like to have something like Xmx=130000M (or even Xmx=135000M). I want to have as much JVM memory as possible.

Curently i can not jump over 111000M it says Out of Heap Space

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-Xms111000M
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-Xmx111000M
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-XX:PermSize=64M
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-XX:MaxPermSize=256M
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-d64
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-XX:+UseParallelOldGC
```

And i really have to have Xms=Xmx 
I tried a lot of options and I could not jump over. 
Is it possible to have "bit" extra memory?

Regards
Bob

Comment: When you specify `111000M`, what is the actual amount of memory that gets used at the OS level? The amount allocated will always be Heap + RAM for VM. I wouldn't think that the VM would take up more memory just because you're using a larger heap, but since I don't have a machine w/144GB of RAM sitting around to test my theory, maybe you can try it and tell me what happens?

Comment: When do you get the heap error? What if you specify in gigabytes instead of megabytes (e.g. -Xmx128g)? Some other debugging notes http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html

Comment: 111000M ought to be enough for everyone... (sorry i coudln't resist) :)

Comment: How much free memory and swap do you have before you start tomcat? What is the maximum memory size for each process? i.e. ulimit -a

Comment: You may find that if the application cross over more than one memory bank (numa region) your GC times increase significantly. What is your full GC time for a process with 110G ?

Comment: You get an out of heap space with 144GB? Maybe the problem is not the heap configuration, but rather on application level.

Comment: I agree with @PeterLawrey, you'll probably find that if you manage to reach, say 75% of this RAM usage, then GC will be so slow that you may still get out of memory errors.  You'd be better off running multiple instances of Tomcat.  If you can, simulate the load with JMeter or something to figure out what happens.

Comment: I'm just curious what all the memory is for? Have you considered moving some objects out of the JVM into memcache or Redis? You can do distributed memcache where objects are spread over smaller much cheaper servers...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Java needs a bit of memory to manage the heap. So if you allocate 1GB heap, it will allocate 1.5GB (heap + permgen + code space + ....). So you need to check how much memory Java really allocates from the OS when you say `-Xms111000M -Xmx111000M`. Note that you need `-Xms` or Java will slowly allocate the memory and it will be hard to test the OOM condition.

Also make sure that you actually have that much memory available in a single chunk. So maybe some other process needs a lot of RAM or your RAM is split into two smaller chunks (should not happen with a MMU since all pages for a process will always appear to be continuous but maybe you've found a bug).

Answer (score -1):

I know that 111000M ought to be enough for everyone ..... but it is not. 
I do have 144GB of real memory + 200GB swap (I know, I know ....)

Problem starts when I start TOMCAT.

I am using LINUX as my OS. In catalina.sh i use those options

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-Xms111000M
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-Xmx111000M
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-XX:PermSize=64M
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-XX:MaxPermSize=256M
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-d64
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-XX:+UseParallelOldGC
```

I really need memory and those "extra" 20GB will make a difference for some time (i know that I will need to upgrade memory soon (192 because of

hardware limit and buy new server wuth 512GB ram but it will be in the future. I am nowhere near there [yet])

I did get out of Heap space I did continue decreasing (from 135000) by 1000 and TOMCAT did start to work when i reached 111000M

I do not have anything else running on that server.

On "idle" when TOMCAT is stoppped LINUX "takes" ~ 800-900MB of RAM. I have never reached more than 1GB ram on "idle" (of couse it is ~500M after

restart and than "grow" to ~1GB).

SO i do have 143-GB RAM (let say 140GB RAM).

I would really love to get 135000M. I know that it is a lot of increase but application that is installed on TOMCAT eats memory (really does).

So far I have found that when Xms=Xmx - performance is far the best (and it soles lots of JAVA problems - but that is what we experienced over the

years).

Those setting

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-Xms111000M
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-Xmx111000M
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-XX:PermSize=64M
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-XX:MaxPermSize=256M
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-d64
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-XX:+UseParallelOldGC
```

Work for us the best. We did try a lot of different options (not all to be honest) and those ones works. 
But those exta 20GB RAM.......

What is your full GC time for a process with 110G (Server is 4x6core (hyperthreaded cpu) so 24cores, 48threads) takes ~ 3- minutes. In the code we

"force" to run full GC overnight as a part of maintenance process.

Emil: Thank you for the tip with using G instead of M. I will try that. 
And following that link you gave me. I have never came across BigApp option.
I will try that.

Before i start tomcat i do have memory avalible.

I did even fresh restarts and start from 0 (should be from 0 to hero but .....).

I do have few smaller servers (128GB ram and 4x4core CPUs) aI will try to make changes there. If works that OK if not - will dig further

Thank you 
Bob

Comment: That's not an answer to your question.